# Installing PyCuda package shows cl.exe error in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pycharm, pycuda, cl.exe

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I'm trying to install PyCuda package for my program and I get the above error. The IDE I use is Pycharm.
My pip version is 10.0.1. What could be the possible issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using these steps:

1. Install Cuda Toolkit from NVIDIA website
2. Open [This link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycuda) and download appropriate PyCuda whl file for your python version and system
3. Install the  downloaded package using Anaconda
4. Open PyCharm and install the package using *Interpreter settings*
5. Enjoy PyCuda

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From `pycharm`,

goto `settings` -> `project Interpreter`

Click on `+` button on top right corner and you will get pop-up window of Available packages. Then search for `pycuda` python package.

Then click on Install package to install the package.

Comment: I tried it, but didn't work. Thanks for help anyway. I've found another solution